# How do you get C++ to compile from Code::BLocks? (Beginner to Linux)

Tags: c++, ide, code-blocks

So I just recently installed Linux after using Windows for my whole life. I also just installed the C++ IDE named `code::blocks` using the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install codeblocks
```

Now whenever I try to run some source code I get this error

```
sh:1 /home/daniel/Desktop/Hey: Permission Denied
```

Any help/solution?

Comment: Did you save the source file with a `.cpp` extension? I have seen that error when someone saves without an extension.

Comment: Thanks.... really amazing community this is... sorry for my broken English (not my first language and I'm only 13) and yeah that fixed the problem!! Thanks very much

Answer (score 3):

The normal behaviour of CodeBlocks when working on a single file (as opposed to a project) is to use the name of the file without any extension as the name of the compiled executable. So `hello.cpp` will produce a binary named `hello`. CodeBlocks checks the timestamps of the files to see whether compilation is needed. This breaks when the file doesn't have an extension: a source file named `hello` would have a binary file named `hello` from CodeBlocks' point-of-view. So timestamp checking fails, since it is comparing the file to itself. Hence CodeBlocks doesn't compile the code, and instead tries to run it directly, where it fails because the source file is not an executable. (This won't be a problem for executable source code like shell scripts.)

So always save C/C++ source code with an appropriate extension when using CodeBlocks (and in general, as well).

Comment: I would add that G++ is meant to work on Windows too, so it requires `.cpp`, or better `.c++` extension for source files.

Comment: @enedil I have never seen a file with a `.c++` extension and I'd recommend against it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171502/c-vs-cc-vs-cpp-vs-hpp-vs-h-vs-cxx

Comment: I won't find that document but I was reading a C++ style guideline which was recommending .c++.